# Name of truncation pattern "+1 more"

Tags: terminology, component

Is there a proper name of the function "+1 more/other". It‘s some kind of truncation, but maybe it has a specific name?
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe there is a more specific term for “+X more”. I think you’ve got it with calling it “truncation”. In practice I’ve usually heard it be called just a “more button”, as in “show 5 items and hide the rest behind a more button”.

I do think there is a name for the special case of “+1 more”. It’s called “being useless”. Instead of adding a “+1 more” button, show the item itself, there’s room for it if the button is not shown. (This can even apply to +2 or +3 sometimes)